# Apache FOP ClassNotFoundException/ClassCircularityError On Weblogic11g

Tags: spring, weblogic, classloader, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP 1.1
within EJB3 and Spring 3.0.6 web application.
The code:

`FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();`

resides in my class, (which is being called from a Spring MVC converter).
I get **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** exception if this code is outside the method (class level), and **java.lang.ClassCircularityError** exception is this line is inside the method.

Please see the class bellow:

`@Component
public class PdfReport  extends  BaseReportImpl implements IPdfReport{`

```
@Override
public void createReport(OutputStream out, ResponseData responseData) throws IOException {
    try {
        //Construct a FopFactory
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

        //Construct fop with desired output format
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

        //Setup JAXP using identity transformer
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        //identity transformer
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

        //Setup input stream
        Source src = new StreamSource(new File("/resources/detailsReport.fo"));

        //Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        //Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
        transformer.transform(src, res);

    } catch (FOPException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed creating PDF report: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed setting up transformer for PDF report: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed transforming PDF report: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } 
}
```

}

But on that line I get an exception:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/apache/fop/apps/FOPException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at utils.spring.UnloadFilterBean.doFilterInternal(UnloadFilterBean.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/apache/fop/apps/FOPException
    at proj.report.PdfReport.createReport(PdfReport.java:37)
    at protocol.ResponseDataConverter.writeInternal(ResponseDataConverter.java:94)
    at protocol.ResponseDataConverter.writeInternal(ResponseDataConverter.java:1)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.writeWithMessageConverters(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:996)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.handleResponseBody(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:954)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:903)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:438)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    ... 26 more`

Please help!

**Addition:**
If I move `FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();` outside the createReport() method, I get the exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
    ... 86 more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the FOP jars in the eclipse file org.eclipse.wst.common.component for the exploded EAR file creation.